# batch script to compress files that are older than 7 days

Tags: batch-file, zip

How can I change this script so that will only compresses the files that are older than 7 days?

```
FOR %%A IN (D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.txt*, D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\"%%~nA.zip" "%%A"

FOR %%A IN (D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.TXT,D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.cpi) DO DEL "D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\.cpi*" "%%A"
```

Regards, Jason

Answer (score 3):

Just use `WinRAR`'s `-to` switch, which instructs the archiver to process only files older than the specified period of time. The period should be a string consisting of numeric values and units:

```
NNNdNNNhNNNmNNNs
```

where the *`NNN`*'s are numeric values and **`d`** (days), **`h`** (hours), **`m`** (minutes), **`s`** (seconds) are valid unit designators.

You don't have to specify all the units. For instance, in your case, the period would be just `7d`:

```
FOR %%A IN (
  D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.txt*
  D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.cpi*
) DO (
  "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -to7d D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\"%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
)
```

If no file is matching the specified period, the archive doesn't get created/updated.

Comment: Ah, much better than my answer!  If WinRAR has command line options for this, use them!

Answer (score 2):

Robocopy is able to copy files based on age.  I'd use robocopy to move the files to a temporary directory, then zip the contents of that directory.

For example (untested):

```
SET SourceDir=C:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup
SET TmpDir=C:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\tmpbackup

ROBOCOPY "%SourceDir%" "%TmpDir%" *.txt *.cpi /MOV /MINAGE:7 
FOR %%A IN (%TmpDir%\*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a "%SourceDir%\%%~nA.zip" "%%A" 
RMDIR /S /Q "%TmpDir%"
```

Comment: Thanks Kelly. I will try this and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok i tested the commands you provided above. The command executes without errors but all it does is it deletes the TmpDir. I have the files that needs to be zipped in backup folder and i created a tmp directory to test this command. This is the command i executed. 
SET SourceDir=D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\
SET TmpDir=D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\tmpbackup

robocopy "%SourceDir%" "%TmpDir%" *.txt* *.cpi* /MOV /MINAGE:7
FOR %%A IN (%TmpDir%\*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%SourceDir%%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
rmdir /s /q "%SourceDir%"

Comment: Looks like you missed a \ in the `FOR`:  `%TmpDir%\*.*`.  That would cause the `FOR` not to find any matching files.

Comment: Ok i tested the commands you provided above. The command executes without errors but all it does is that it copies the files from backup folder to backup\MansoorBackup and then  deletes the backup folder without zipping the files in the MansoorBackup folder

Comment: If it's correctly moving the right files to the temporary folder but just not zipping them, then there's something wrong with the `FOR` loop or with your WinRAR command line.  You'll have to troubleshoot.  Stick an `ECHO` in there to see what it's trying to do: `FOR %%A IN (%TmpDir%\*.*) DO ECHO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a "%SourceDir%\%%~nA.zip" "%%A"`, and make sure the WinRAR command line looks as you expect.  Try running WinRAR yourself at the command line exactly as the ECHO command did and then tweak the command line until it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you Nate. you were right i missed a \ in the FOR:%TmpDir%\*.*. Now the script is working just fine:) Also Is it possible to create the zip files with the same file creation date as the origininal files (non-zipped files)? (e.g SomeFile.txt created_on 1-oct-2012 After zipping the zip file should also say someFile.zip created_date 1-oct-2012)

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a new question.  If one of the answers on this page has been helpful to you, please consider marking it as "accepted".

Comment: Ok Thanks Nate. I will as this as a new Question.